# Teradata: How can I drop a foreign key constraint from a table?

Tags: foreign-keys, teradata

I created a table then added a foreign key reference to its primary key in another table.  I need to drop the new table to recreate it with additional columns (I do not want to add the new columns to it).  When I attempt to delete it, it tells me I cannot deleted a referenced table.  So I try to drop the foreign key column from the other table and it tells me that the foreign key column cannot be dropped.  This leaves me with removing the foreign key itself first, but I don't know the name of it.  I came upon this link:

http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/how-to-drop-a-constraint-without-knowing-its-name

...but it is no help.  I can't seem to locate the name of this foreign key anywhere.  Any help on how to drop this foreign key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE {MyDB}.{MyTable} DROP FOREIGN KEY ({ColumnList}) REFERENCES {MyDB}.{MyOtherTable};
```

Comment: This worked great.  I don't know how I couldn't find such a simple solution elsewhere.  Thanks!

Comment: Download a copy of the manuals from http://www.info.teradata.com/edownload.cfm?itemid=102370003 (TD 13.10 User Documentation). If you are a on a different version then go to http://www.info.teradata.com/Datawarehouse/eBrowseBy.cfm?page=TeradataDatabase and find the appropriate version.

Comment: Just for the record, the foreign key reference was implemented with soft referential integrity on my side. I reused the response above and updated it as follow: `ALTER TABLE {MyDB}.{MyTable} DROP FOREIGN KEY ({Column}) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION {MyDB}.{MyOtherTable}({Column});`